# Disallow compromising aliases & functions; alias cd='rm -rf ~'

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

Lets say someone sits behind my laptop for a second and runs:

```bsh
alias cd='Ha Ha, Got You :))'
```

or we run an unknown software/script/etc and it appends something to `~/.bashrc`. like:

```bsh
alias sort='rm -rf ~'
```

These are only examples of `aliases`; As you know, these things also can be done using functions:

```bsh
 cd(){ echo "Removing everything you've got :D"; }
```

*These situations are just imaginary examples, consider anything similar.*

What about a small script?

```bsh
sudo -n ls &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
 then
  sudo "Some dangerous command"
 else
  cd $1
fi
```

Then `alias cd="/home/user/.config/gtk/.cd.sh"`.

For the commands which have been ran in bash we can simply close and reopen our terminal, but what about the ones that been set in startup files, we can't check the files or list of aliases/functions every single time we run a terminal.

Comment: Any idea how to disallow malicious aliases and functions in an interactive non-login shell, besides just restarting the terminal?

Comment: Okay, here is two: first is going into another shell -> `/bin/bash`; the other is keeping a list of aliases in a script at a safe place (permission) which contains something like `unalias -a; alias x='...'; alias y='...';`. then running it with absolute path: `/usr/local/bin/reload_aliases`.

Comment: _Never_ let untrusted people run commands in your name. _Never_ let untrusted people run commands in your name. _Never_ let untrusted people run commands in your name. _Never_ let untrusted people run commands in your name. Most work places will insist that you lock your workstation whenever you leave your desk, _and will hold you responsible_ for anything your workstation does.

Comment: +1 @AlexP I want to add more " there is no patch available for human stupidity " no hard feelings , I read that somewhere :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

#### Bash configuration files

Bash has a bunch of configuration (aka startup) files, it uses these files to setup a specific environment for each user.

Some of these files are located at `/etc`, one of them that I'm aware of is `/etc/profile`, it's a global configuration file and its settings will be applied into all sessions, another is `/etc/bash.bashrc`; We don't need to work around these files because of their location they already are protected and only root has the rights to edit them.

A very important directory which can help us a lot is: `/etc/skel`; Whenever you create a new user with home directory, the files within this directory will be used as a skeleton for your new user's home directory.

```
ls -a /etc/skel

.bash_logout  .bashrc  .profile
```

We can also use `dpkg` to find about these files:

```
$ dpkg -L bash | grep etc

/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bash_logout
/etc/skel/.profile
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

we can see that these all are installed by `bash`.

#### How thing works in bash

An alias or function can be set in any of these files, so let see how these files will be used by `bash`.

From `bash` man page:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the  file /etc/profile,  if  that  file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and exe‐cutes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

so the order is: `~/.bash_profile > ~/.bash_login > ~/.profile`

> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

this one will be run every time we exit from a login shell, I can't see how this one can has any effects on our situation.

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if  these  files  exist.

so the most important fiel is `~/.bashrc`, because almost 90% of bash shells which we run are in interactive and no-login mode. and if we have a look at this file we can see that it will look for another file named `~/.bash_aliases`, if it was able to locate it, then it will `source` that file too.

---

### Start taking care of these files

First of all we should move `~/.profile` to `~/.bash_profile` otherwise it does not matters if we protect `~/.profile` file, someone can create a `~/.bash_profile` and it will overrides our configs, so:

```
mv ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile
```

After that if you are not using a `~/.bash_aliases` file then create it, again like above, someone can simply create this file and there is a chance that (s)he can alter or aliases within it.

```
touch ~/.bash_aliases
```

Finally use `chattr` to protect these files against edit and removal.

From `chattr` man page:

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.bash_profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_aliases
```

We are done, Don't forget that whenever you want to edit these files you should first remove the `-i` attribute.

**Reset everything without close/reopening terminal**

Another workaround is, creating a file:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/reload_aliases
```

Put your aliases there:

```
unalias -a
alias x='...'
alias b='...'
```

Make sure nobody can write into that file:

```
sudo chmod a=r,x /usr/local/bin/reload_aliases
```

Now every time you want to reload everything run:

```
/usr/local/bin/reload_aliases
```

---

#### Rollback

And if you ever changed your mind:

```
sudo chattr -i ~/.bash_profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_aliases
mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile
rm ~/.bash_aliases # if you don't use it
```

Comment: Won't defend against `bash --rcfile=/home/evil/bashrc.bad` (and let the luser issue commands to that shell).

Comment: Can you explain it more? I can't get it how it's possible... cause definitely I'm not going to run such a command myself.

Comment: As O.P. said, he fears a Bad Guy executing a command defining evil aliases. You offered what was supposed to prevent this. I gave a proof-of-concept that it would not prevent this. Read `man bash`, and search for `--rcfile`. It says "`Execute   commands   from   file  *instead*  of  the  system  wide initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the  standard  personal
 initialization  file  ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive (see
  INVOCATION below).`" (My asterisks)

Comment: What if we close and reopen the terminal? that would do the work right?

Answer (score 0):

If you do stupid things (walk away without locking screen, blindly run uninspected scripts from untrusted sources, etc), you will get bad results.

Trying to be clever enough to recover from bad practices has never worked before.